# SQL Syntax in PHP Laravel Query Builder PostgreSQLvs MySQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and have a sql query using the query builder functions and have broken a query when switching from a MySQL database to PostgreSQL. The query is meant to get all locations within a certain number of miles of a latitude and longitude.

```
    $locations = Location::select(
        DB::raw("*,
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                cos( radians( lat) )
                * cos( radians( long ) - radians(?)
                ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                sin( radians( lat ) ) )
            ) AS distance"))
        ->having("distance", "<", $distance)
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->setBindings([$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
        ->get();
```

Once switching to the PostgreSQL data source, I get this error:

```
QLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "distance" does not exist
LINE 7: ) AS distance from "locations" having "distance" < $4 o...
^ (SQL: select *,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37.7959362) ) *
cos( radians( lat ) )
* cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122.4000032)
) + sin( radians(37.7959362) ) *
sin( radians( lat ) ) )
) AS distance from "locations" having "distance" < 15 order by "distance" asc)
```

What would be the best way to fix this problem. I know it's a difference in the SQL syntax between MySQL and Postgres that is created by Laravel but I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to fix this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `having` clause. PostgreSQL does not allow using a derived column (or column alias) in the having clause, whereas MySQL does (as long as you have MySQL Extensions to Group By enabled, which is enabled by default).

One option to get around this restriction is to use a derived table, so that the field is available for the `having` clause. Something like below (warning: completely untested):

```
$locations = Location::from(DB::raw("(select *,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
            cos( radians( lat) )
            * cos( radians( long ) - radians(?)
            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
        ) AS distance from locations) as t"))
    ->having("distance", "<", $distance)
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->setBindings([$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @patricus! I was able to get to the solution using your suggestion to use a derived table. I had to add a group by clause that looked like this: ->groupBy(DB::raw('id, title, address_1 ...')).